# asynchronous Task not working when using searchable activity :App crash

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-post, google-places-api

I'm trying to make an activity that enables me to search for restaurants by name.
for that I'm using the android search widget.

I'm also using google places API Text Search Service to get the list of restaurants that match the search query.

I have basically two classes:

1. The class form where I call the searchableActivity "nearest restaurants"
2. The class that displays my results. "searchable activity"

I'm using an asychronous task to get the google places API Text Search Service and to diplay them in th UI.

My problem is when I try to call the SearchableActivity from NearestRestaurantsActivity the application crashes.
Using the stack trace I figured out where the problem comes from:
getTextPlaces() in doInbackground() returns null , Iguess it's because the http post 
connection is not working, And I really do not know how to encounter this problem I searched a lot but without any valuable result!!

here is the code that I'm using:

**My manifest file:**

```
<!-- Internet Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- Network State Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- Access Location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<!-- List of nearest restaurants -->
<activity
android:name="com.nearest_restaurants.Nearest_Restaurants"
android:label="nearest restaurants" >
      <meta-data
       android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
       android:value=".nearest_restaurants.SearchableActivity" />
</activity>
<!--Contains the list of restaurants  that match  the text query -->
<activity android:name=".nearest_restaurants.SearchableActivity"
          android:launchMode="singleTop" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
</intent-filter>
     <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
</activity>
```

**the nearestrestaurants activity** from where I call the SearchableActivity :

```
      /*****search restaurant by name with the search widget***/

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
     Log.d("oncreateOptionMenu",""+menu);
     SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
     SearchView searchView =
             (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.searchit).getActionView();
      searchView.setSearchableInfo(
             searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
     //searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);

    return true;
}
```

**SearchableActivity:**

```
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.nearest_restaurants);
      Intent intent = getIntent();
      if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
           query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
          Log.d("Event",query);
          //an asychronous task to search the restaurants by name 
          LoadPlacesByText loadplaces= new LoadPlacesByText();
          loadplaces.execute();  
      }

 /**
     * Background Async Task to Load Google places
     * */
    class LoadPlacesByText extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */


        /**
         * getting Places JSON
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // creating Places class object
            googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces();
            nearPlaces = new PlacesList();
            try {
                // Separeate your place types by PIPE symbol "|"
                // If you want all types places make it as null
                // Check list of types supported by google


                String types = "cafe|restaurant"; // Listing places only cafes, restaurants

                // Radius in meters - increase this value if you don't find any places
                double radius = 100; // 1000 meters 
                Log.d( "QUERY", query);
                // get  places list

                nearPlaces = googlePlaces.getTextPlaces(query,gps.getLatitude(),gps.getLongitude() ,radius, types);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d( "QUERY", query);
                Log.d("Exeptionstack", ""+e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "n";
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            //pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread

                    /**
                     * Updating parsed Places into LISTVIEW
                     * */
                    // Get json response status

                    String status = nearPlaces.status;

                    // Check for all possible status
                    if(status.equals("OK")){
                        // Successfully got places details
                        if (nearPlaces.results != null) {
                            // loop through each place
                            for (Place p : nearPlaces.results) {
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                // Place reference won't display in list View - it will be hidden
                                // Place reference is used to get "place full details"
                                map.put(KEY_REFERENCE, p.reference);

                                // Place name
                                map.put(KEY_NAME, p.name);


                                // adding HashMap to ArrayList
                                placesListItems.add(map);
                            }
                            // list adapter
                            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), placesListItems,
                                    R.layout.list_item,
                                    new String[] { KEY_REFERENCE, KEY_NAME}, new int[] {
                                            R.id.reference, R.id.name });

                            // Adding data into listview
                            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("ZERO_RESULTS")){
                        // Zero results found
                        alert.showAlertDialog(getApplicationContext(), "Near Places",
                                "Sorry no places found. Try to change the types of places",
                                false);
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("UNKNOWN_ERROR"))
                    {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(getApplicationContext(), "Places Error",
                                "Sorry unknown error occured.",
                                false);
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"))
                    {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(getApplicationContext(), "Places Error",
                                "Sorry query limit to google places is reached",
                                false);
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("REQUEST_DENIED"))
                    {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(getApplicationContext(), "Places Error",
                                "Sorry error occured. Request is denied",
                                false);
                    }
                    else if(status.equals("INVALID_REQUEST"))
                    {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(getApplicationContext(), "Places Error",
                                "Sorry error occured. Invalid Request",
                                false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(getApplicationContext(), "Places Error",
                                "Sorry error occured.",
                                false);
                    }
                }


    }
```

**getTextPlaces** method:

```
     public PlacesList getTextPlaces(String query,double latitude, double longitude,  double radius, String types) 
   throws Exception {

    this._latitude = latitude;
    this._longitude = longitude;
    this._radius = radius;


    try {

        HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
        HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_TEXT_SEARCH_URL));
        request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
        request.getUrl().put("location", _latitude + "," + _longitude);
        request.getUrl().put("radius", _radius); // in meters
        request.getUrl().put("sensor", "true");
        if(types != null)
            request.getUrl().put("types", types);
        request.getUrl().put("query", query);
        request.getUrl().put("sensor", "true");

        PlacesList list = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
        // Check log cat for places response status
        Log.d("Places Status", "" + list.status);
        return list;

    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        Log.d("Error:", e.getMessage());
        Log.d("Its an Httpresponse exeption","");
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Creating http request Factory
 * */
public static HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(
        final HttpTransport transport) {
    return transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
            GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
            headers.setApplicationName("app_name");
            request.setHeaders(headers);
            JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory());
            request.addParser(parser);
        }
    });
}
```

and here is the **stack trace**:

```
    W/System.err(14206): java.lang.NullPointerException 
    W/System.err(14206): at      com.nearest_restaurants.SearchableActivity$LoadPlacesByText.doInBackground(SearchableActivi ty.java:160)
    W/System.err(14206):    at com.nearest_restaurants.SearchableActivity$LoadPlacesByText.doInBackground(SearchableActivity.java:1)
    W/System.err(14206):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    W/System.err(14206):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    W/System.err(14206):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    W/System.err(14206):    at  android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
   W/System.err(14206):     at  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
   W/System.err(14206):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
   W/System.err(14206):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)


   E/AndroidRuntime(14206): FATAL EXCEPTION: main   
   E/AndroidRuntime(14206): java.lang.NullPointerException// comes from nearplaces in doInbackground
   E/AndroidRuntime(14206):     at com.nearest_restaurants.SearchableActivity$LoadPlacesByText.onPostExecute(SearchableActivity.java:191)
   E/AndroidRuntime(14206):     at com.nearest_restaurants.SearchableActivity$LoadPlacesByText.onPostExecute(SearchableActivity.java:1)
   E/AndroidRuntime(14206):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
   E/AndroidRuntime(14206):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
   E/AndroidRuntime(14206):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
   E/AndroidRuntime(14206):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   E/AndroidRuntime(14206):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   E/AndroidRuntime(14206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
   E/AndroidRuntime(14206):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   E/AndroidRuntime(14206):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   E/AndroidRuntime(14206):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
   E/AndroidRuntime(14206):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
   E/AndroidRuntime(14206):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

PS: 
I have put an edittext with a button in the NearestPlacesActivity, in the onclick event I started another activity where I call LoadPlacesByText() and it works fine! 
So I don't know if this has something to do the search widget.

I modified a bit LoadPlaces asynctask from this post 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/ to use it in LoadPlacesByText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out what was the problem, I had to increase the connection timeout 
So added those both lines of code:

in doInBackground() :

```
         Thread.sleep(1000);
```

and in getTextPlaces():

```
         request.setConnectTimeout(50000);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use classes in Apache's org.apache.http.client package. It would simply reduce your effort.
A sample code:

```
public static String connectToServer(String url, List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {
        String result = null;
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);

        // Instantiate an HttpClient 
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams); 
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url); // Instantiate a POST HTTP method
        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            result = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the getTextPlaces() method returns null just when I use it in the searchable activity!! I have put an edittext with a button in the NearestPlacesActivity, and in the onclick event I started another activity where I call LoadPlacesByText() and the getTextPlaces()worked fine and returned the list of places as expected! so now I really do not know where the problem comes from!